# Is it possible for a video segment to be encoded at a higher bitrate than the video segment in the source file?

Tags: encoding, handbrake, bitrate

I am currently experimenting with video compression on Handbrake and I would like to know if suppose a video segment in the source file is around 11000 kb/s, is it possible for it to be somehow encoded at a higher bitrate like around 15000 kb/s.

And if it is, would there be no increase in the segment quality and just give me a larger file size since the source has a lower bitrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible and in almost all cases it will result in a bigger file with the.same or worse quality output.

I believe that there are some filters which can increase the perceived quality, but they are VERY computationally expensive. (They do things like look for math patterns and then fill in missing information). I would be surprised if Handbrake has such a filter.